# Are there any tools to test font size and font family mobile application?

Tags: automated-testing, mobile

- In my project, I need to test mobile app for font size, font family. Are there any tools to help with that?
  Like: DOM,fire bug
- I's also like to know if there is any automation tool for mobile testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a font-family is set on the body tag in your stylesheet, then that font will apply to nearly every element throughout your site (form and table elements being the exception where you have to redeclare the font-family for those).

The only time the font-family declared on the body won't apply is if it's overridden by a different font-family applied on individual elements elsewhere in the stylesheet, or if it is applied by inline styles.

So you can check on font-family consistency in the stylesheet/s just be doing a search for 'font:' (for cases where shorthand is being used) and 'font-family' and making sure any references to it match what your default font should be.